# Fixed stroke width in SVG

Tags: svg, visualization

I would like to be able to set the stroke-width on an SVG element to be "pixel-aware", that is always be 1px wide regardless of the current scaling transformations applied. I am aware that this may well be impossible, since the whole point of SVG is to be pixel independent.

Context follows:

I have an SVG element with its viewBox and preserveAspectRatio attributes set. It looks something like this

```
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full"
    viewBox="-100 -100 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
</svg>
```

This means that when I scale that element, the actual shapes inside it scale accordingly (so far so good).

As you can see, I have set up the viewBox so that the origin is in the center. I would like to draw an x- and a y-axis within that element, which I do thus:

```
<line x1="-1000" x2="1000" y1="0" y2="0" />
```

Again, this works fine. Ideally, though, this axis would always be only 1px wide. I have no interest in the axes getting fatter when i scale the parent svg element.

So am I screwed?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You can use the `vector-effect` property set to `non-scaling-stroke`, see [the docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#NonScalingStroke). Another way is to use [`transform(ref)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/coords.html#transform-ref).

That will work in browsers that support those parts from SVG Tiny 1.2, for example Opera 10. The fallback includes writing a small script to do the same, basically inverting the CTM and applying it on the elements that shouldn't scale.

If you want sharper lines you can also [disable antialiasing](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#ShapeRenderingProperty) (`shape-rendering=optimizeSpeed` or `shape-rendering=crispEdges`) and/or play with the positioning.

Comment: Unfortunately this is in a XUL app, and that doesn't seem to support vector-effect yet. Oh well.

Comment: This should appear in Firefox 15 all being well so you should be able to use it once you build your XUL app on gecko 15.

Comment: IE11 still doesn't support `vector-effect` property. Is it possible to achieve the same effect as `vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke` in IE11?

Comment: @merlin yes, with js it's possible to emulate this in IE.

Comment: @ErikDahlström You mean inverting the CTM and applying it on the elements that shouldn't scale? But stroke is not represent by element. How can i apply the inverting to it? Would be awesome if you can provide a code snippet to illustrate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @merlin clone the element (setting `fill` to `none` and vice versa for the `stroke`), compute & set the appropriate transforms (one for the fill part and one for the stroke part). It's going to be a little messy for sure, but there it is - you might also want to ask Microsoft to add support for it. In any case I think your question deserves to be a question of its own.

Comment: @ErikDahlström would it be possible for you to show some code which achieves what you described in the last comment?

Comment: Should this approach work with browser zoom, or only SVG scaling transformations?

Comment: I could not get non-scaling-stroke working in current Edge or FF versions. I had the impression, that the effects got even worse. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357292/how-to-make-stroke-width-immune-to-the-current-transformation-matrix gives some explanation.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a more concise answer based  on Erik's answer to help you get started quickly.

```html
<div style="background: blue; width: 100%; height: 130px;">
            <svg xml:id="root" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <rect xml:id="r" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" stroke="#88CE02"
                      stroke-linecap="square" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="30"/>
            </svg>
        </div>
```

Adding the `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` to the SVG rect makes the border size (or stroke size) fixed.