# SVG Vector Effect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, svg, razor

I am trying to define a fixed stroke width into my SVG, similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301685/fixed-stroke-width-in-svg).

In my devenv (VS 2017) I am running Edge and the project is targeting .net 4.6.1

The SVG is defined as:

```
<svg version="1.1"
    baseProfile="full"
    width="100%" height="Auto"
    viewBox="0 0 @sheet.SheetShape.Bounds.Width @sheet.SheetShape.Bounds.Height"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<rect width="100%" height="100%" stroke="red" fill="white" />

@foreach (var cut in sheet.SheetCuts)
{
    <line vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-width="2" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="5, 5" x1=@cut.Start.X y1=@cut.Start.Y x2=@cut.End.X y2=@cut.End.Y />
}
```

The vector-effect property is not recognized by VS intellisense and when the code runs nothing special happens.

What should be wrong?

Comment: I don't think IE/Microsoft supports this property, only Chrome and Firefox do.

Comment: Thank you @RobertLongson. I did the test and it worked on Firefox indeed. I opened another thread to find a way to calculate this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114996/fixed-stroke-width-calculation